# Django's Inline Forms

Tags: django, view, inline-formset

I am trying to create records using an inline formSet while at the same time creating a record with a normal form whose primary key *is* the foreign key for the inline formSet all on the same HTML page.

Make sense? Here's what I mean: Suppose I have the following two models (not real code, obviously, but you get the idea):

```
Class mainModel
    Primary Key (custom pk I create)
    field1
    field2

Class inlineFormModel
    autoPK
    field1 = ForeignKey(mainModel)
    field2
```

Now, I want to create a single HTML page for the user so they can create a `mainModel` instance at the same time as creating a number of `inlineFormModel` instances. The `mainModel` would be a normal form while the `inlineFormModel` would be using inlineFormsets. The problem is that when I save all the forms, there is no foreignKey to link to the inline formSet records since the model it refers to is still be created (everything gets saved in the same view). Does that make sense?

How would I go about creating a new `mainModel` instance with several `secondModel` instances and save the whole batch all with the same view function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a common scenario, I do not know why is not addressed in the docs:

```
    initial_form = mainModelForm(request.POST)
    if initial_form.is_valid():
        form= initial_form.save(commit=False)
        my_formset = inline_formset(request.POST,instance=form)
        if my_formset.is_valid():
           form.save()
           my_formset.save()
.......  .........
# return codes here
```

Comment: Does it matter if I have 3 inline_formsets all of which have the same initial_form's PK as a Foreign Key?

Comment: so in this case, both the initial form and the formset are rendered inside the same <form> such that all data from both is submitted and defined in request?